# בכר and ברך connection?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot

In this week's parasha, Esav complains that Ya'akov stole both his beracha and his bechor. Do any commentators (either here or elsewhere) comment on the similarity between the words בכר and ברך?

Comment: I believe the Maharal does in a few places but I'm unable to locate them at the moment.